# How to add multiple of the same/array parameter using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have an instance where I need to pass multiple of the same named parameters to a server (array of data).

Changing it is not a possibility.

```
http://test.com?test[]=1&test[]=2&test[]=3
```

How do I accomplish this with RetroFit? I see that you can pass a map of values, but that doesn't help as the keys are all identical.

Any help would be great... really hoping there's a clean way/workaround or else I'm going to need to use another api lib and do a project refactor.

Comment: Are you using retrofit 1.4.+? It looks like arrays were added to a field, but I haven't tried this yet.
`* New: @Field now accepts List or arrays for multiple values.`
`* New: @Query and @EncodedQuery now accept List or arrays for multiple values.`

Comment: You are correct. Found that a few hours ago. If you make that an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I wouldn't call it bizarre. Both html checkbox and select multiple controls will encode the form like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Retrofit as of 1.4.0 added the ability to send an array or List as a `@Field` or `@Query` parameter.

```
New: @Query and @EncodedQuery now accept List or arrays for multiple values.
New: @Field now accepts List or arrays for multiple values.
```

Comment: The relevant lines in source can be found here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/pull/377/files#diff-e552fa8d902af2d67bfdc6362c246f56L190

Comment: Any idea how a similar problem with Part parameter in Multipart can be tackled?

Comment: How do they get encoded I wonder? I will look at the pull request mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

I am using retrofit:1.9.0, one way of doing http://test.com?test[]=1&test[]=2&test[]=3 is like this

```
void test(@Query("test[]") ArrayList<String> values);
```