# Adding duplicate parameters with Retrofit v1.9.0

Tags: android, retrofit

There's a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891148/how-to-add-multiple-of-the-same-parameter-using-retrofit-android), but my case is a bit different.

I'm trying to make a request similar to the following:

http://www.example.com/abc?foo=def&foo=ghi&foo=jkl&bar=xyz

I have two issues that are making things difficult. First, the repeated parameter (setting values for "foo" multiple times) is preventing the use of `QueryMap` (I don't have the option to pass the values in the query string differently, like as an array). Second, the query parameters I'm using are sort of dynamic, so I can't really use `Query` and supply it a list of values for a given parameter name since I won't know the parameter names until I am making the request.

The code I'm trying to upgrade from is using an older version of Retrofit, but somehow it has a concept of a `QueryList` which took a `List` of `NameValuePair`s to pass in query parameters as the name (and their values as the value) and allowing duplicate parameters. I don't see a reference to `retrofit.http.QueryList` anywhere in Retrofit's source code history or on the web, so I'm not sure if this was a custom addition at the time. In any case, I'm trying to find the best way to replicate that functionality in the latest version so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to pass duplicate parameters? It's understandable if it's an array, but your example is simply just a duplicate. Different server may response differently to this, and attackers can use this to exploit the server.

Comment: It's called 'parameter pollution': https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_pollution_%28OTG-INPVAL-004%29

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't have set it up this way and I cringe every time I see it. Unfortunately this is how the server/API I'm using is setup and I don't have control to change it, so I have to work with what I have...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To follow-up, I was able to resolve this by using `QueryMap` and a  bit of a hack. Basically I turn my `List` of `NameValuePair`s into a HashMap where I check if I already have the key, and if I do I append the new value for the same key to the old value. So essentially (key, value) would turn into (key, value&key=value2). This way when the query string is constructed, I'll have key=value&key=value2 as desired. In order for that to work, I need to handle the value encoding myself so that the additional ampersands and equal signs that I'm including in the value don't get encoded.

So the `HashMap` is constructed from the `List` like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> getPathMap(List<NameValuePair> params) {
    HashMap<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
    String paramValue;

    for (NameValuePair paramPair : params) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(paramPair.getName())) {
            try {
                if (paramMap.containsKey(paramPair.getName())) {
                    // Add the duplicate key and new value onto the previous value
                    // so (key, value) will now look like (key, value&key=value2)
                    // which is a hack to work with Retrofit's QueryMap
                    paramValue = paramMap.get(paramPair.getName());
                    paramValue += "&" + paramPair.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(paramPair.getValue()), "UTF-8");
                } else {
                    // This is the first value, so directly map it
                    paramValue = URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(paramPair.getValue()), "UTF-8");
                }
                paramMap.put(paramPair.getName(), paramValue);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return paramMap;
}
```

Then my request looks like this:

```
@GET("/api/")
List<Repo> listRepos(@QueryMap(encodeValues=false) Map<String, String> params);
```

And my service call looks like this:

```
// Get the list of params for the service call
ArrayList<NameValuePair> paramList = getParams();

// Convert the list into a map and make the call with it
Map<String, String> params = getPathMap(paramList);
List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos(params);
```

I originally tried a solution using `Path` where I tried to manually construct the query string, but replacement blocks are not allowed in the query string so I went with this QueryMap solution. Hopefully this helps anyone else that runs into the same issue!

Comment: Thank you, your solution saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 2):

Interface:

```
@GET()
Call<List<CustomDto>> getCustomData(@Url String url);
```

Request data:

```
 String params = "custom?";
 for (Integer id : ids) {
      params += "id=" + id.toString() + "&";
 }
 params = params.substring(0, params.length() - 1);
 api.getCustomData(params).enqueue(callback);
```

Comment: This was the approach that worked for me. I couldn't seem to get the accepted answer to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way of adding duplicate params, available in Retrofit 1.9/2+

```
public interface AbcService {  
    @GET("/abc")
    Call<List<Abc>> getAbcData(@Query("foo") List<String> foos, @Query("bar") String bar);
}
```

where **foos** can be defined like this:

```
List<String> foos = Arrays.asList("def", "ghi", "jkl");
```

for details you can check also this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-multiple-query-parameters-of-same-name)

Answer (score -1):

Just pass a list to your @Query:

```
@GET("/api")
Response shareItem(@Query("email")List<String> email);
```

Comment: I couldn't use a List as I mentioned here:
"Second, the query parameters I'm using are sort of dynamic, so I can't really use Query and supply it a list of values for a given parameter name since I won't know the parameter names until I am making the request."

However, I resolved it via the alternate solution I posted on this page.