# Retrofit - send dynamic queries with same key

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

This is my interface:

```
 public interface ServerCalls{
        @GET
        Call<List<Integer>> searchNames(@Url String url, @QueryMap Map<String, 
        String> options);
    }
 }
```

and this is my call:

```
    APIs.LoadDataService service = 
        retrofit.create(APIs.LoadDataService.class);
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("name","yoni");
        parameters.put("name","albert");
        parameters.put("q","text");
        Call<List<Integer>> call = service.searchNames(APIs.GET_NAMES, parameters);
```

to make a call with dynamic queries i need to used @QueryMap so is mean i need to work with some Map.
my problem is when i need to send the same key because Map get always the last value from key and not supported duplicate.

my api need to get something like that:

```
myapi.com/getLastName?name=yoni&name=albert
```

how can i do it? (without guava library)

Comment: CAn’t you change the API? That’s weird design, if it expects a list of names, then it should be an array in the Body for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding duplicate parameters with Retrofit v1.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776381/adding-duplicate-parameters-with-retrofit-v1-9-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@Query("name") List<String> names`.

Example:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/getLastName")
    Call<ResponseBody> getLastName(@Query("name") List<String> names,
                                   @QueryMap Map<String, String> otherUniqueKeys);
}

List<String> names = new ArrayList();
names.add("yoni");
names.add("albert");

// create an instance of Api interface with retrofit
Api api = ...
api.getLastName(names).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

More details on [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-multiple-query-parameters-of-same-name) link.

Comment: but what is doing is this output:
name=yoni,albert
i need :
name=yoni&name=albert

Comment: @Yoni what version of Retrofit do you use?

Comment: I'm using on Retrofit 2

Comment: @Yoni you do it wrong. I just tested `...random?name=yoni&name=albert ` and is working

Comment: you can show me how you add data to List<String> names?

Comment: I used QueryMap because i need dynamic keys so i cant used @query

Comment: @Yoni Then you add both. You have a list of names with `@Query("name") List<String> names` and `@QueryMap Map<String, String> otherUniqueKeys`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Is this possible @QueryMap Map<String, List<String>>?

Comment: @FlorescuCătălin Thanks a lot!, It works but need to put JvmSuppressWildcards annotation on the service interface

Answer (score 1):

Make interface like this

```
 @POST
 Call<Response> dynamicCall(
        @Url String url,
        @Body Object object);
```

Usage:

```
dynamicCall(url,Object);
```

I hope this will help you.