# Avoid encoding the data while url creation

Tags: java, android, url, encoding, retrofit2

I am trying to make get call like this:

```
 @GET(AppConstants.BASE_URL + "{category_type}/")
    Call<JsonObject> callCustomFilterApI(@Path("category_type") String type,
                                         @QueryMap(encoded = true)  Map<String,String> fields ,
                                         @Query("page") String pageNo);
```

But `@QueryMap` can have *"&"* in the data, so retrofit encoding it to *%26*.

Is there anyway "&" do not change to "%26".

Solution I tried:

1. [Solution mentioned here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1407)
2. setting encoded=true/false
3. [And also this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28822411/1640009).

   @DebDeep Asked:

I am passing data in QueryMap as:

```
 private void callCustomFilterSearchPagesApi(String type,  ArrayList<FilterListWithHeaderTitle> customFiltersList, int pageNumber, final ApiInteractor listener) {
        Map<String, String> queryMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (FilterListWithHeaderTitle item: customFiltersList) {

                String pairValue;
                if (queryMap.containsKey(item.getHeaderTitle())){
                    // Add the duplicate key and new value onto the previous value
                    // so (key, value) will now look like (key, value&key=value2)
                    // which is a hack to work with Retrofit's QueryMap

                    String oldValue=queryMap.get(item.getHeaderTitle());
                    String newValue="filters[" + item.getHeaderTitle() + "][]"
                            +oldValue+ "&"+"filters[" + item.getHeaderTitle() + "][]"+item.getFilterItem();
                    pairValue=newValue;
                }else {
                    // adding first time
                    pairValue= item.getFilterItem();
                }
                try {
                    //pairValue= URLEncoder.encode(pairValue, "utf-8");
                   // LoggerUtils.logE(TAG,pairValue);
                    //queryMap.put(item.getHeaderTitle(), Html.fromHtml(pairValue).toString());
                    queryMap.put(item.getHeaderTitle(), pairValue);

                }catch (Exception u){
                    LoggerUtils.crashlyticsLog(TAG,u.getMessage());
                }

            }
            Call<JsonObject> call = TagTasteApplicationInitializer.mRetroClient.callCustomFilterApI(type, queryMap, "1");
            requestCall(call, listener);
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199

Comment: @NileshRathod value parameter not available for QueryMap field

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap

Comment: How are you adding data to the `QueryMap`?

Comment: Use `OkHttp` `Interceptor` to replace the generated url string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Interceptor` and convert `%26` to `&`:

```
class RequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        String stringurl = request.url().toString();
        stringurl = stringurl.replace("%26", "&");

        Request newRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .url(stringurl)
                .build();

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
    }
}
```

Set this to your `OkHttp` builder:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
client.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
```